# How to fix "Guru Meditation Error" caused by http.GET();?

Tags: http-get, esp32

I want to send data on my web server from esp32. ESP32 can not get to website and reboot.

I used exaples from Arduino IDE.
I've tried to post(htt.POST("X")) something and got same error.
I marked code to find which line cause the problem.
Googled.

```
...
msg="192.168.4.22/parametr";
if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){ 

   if(client.connect(host,httpPort)){
      http.begin(msg); 
      Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
      int httpCode = http.GET();
      Serial.print("1");    
...
```

I expect to get to website, but now esp32 reboots when achived http.GET() and never prints "1".
Error message: Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are passing to `http.begin()` is incorrect. You need to include the `http://` prefix (see [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L135)). Semantically, it makes more sense to name this variable `url` rather than `msg`.

Also ... Check the return value of `http.begin()` - in case it is still failing.

```c
    const char *url = "http://192.168.4.22/parametr";
    // Check Wi-Fi connected, etc.

    if (!http.begin(url)) {
        Serial.println("HTTP client failed to connect ...");
    }
    else {
        int httpCode = http.GET();
        // etc.
    }
```

The `LoadProhibited` fatal error indicates an attempt to read or write an invalid memory location. When the library failed to parse the URL you provided, some member of the `HTTPClient` object may have been left uninitialized.

### Log output

To assist your debugging, try setting the 'Core debug level' in the Arduino IDE to 'Debug'.

> Arduino IDE -> Tools -> Core Debug Level -> Debug

This will ensure that the ESP log messages - such as might be printed [if initialization of the HTTP client fails](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L138) - will be printed over the serial port.

For example, this is the log output I see if I fail to include the `http://` protocol specifier in the URL (after changing the core debug level).

[image: ESP32 log output for HTTP client]

Comment: Thank You very much, I used http prefix earlier , but probably while solveing another problems, I deleted it.
I used `msg` instead of `url`, beacuese earlier it was TCP connection and I left it.

Comment: @PawełStępniak: You are welcome. Did adding the `http://` prefix - and/or checking the return value of `http.begin()` - solve the issue for you?

BTW: I have updated the answer with a suggestion on how to improve the debugging experience by changing the log level in the Arduino IDE.